# futuristic scifi story about a girl who gets sucked into a mirror to another time/place?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

i remember reading this story a long time ago in middle school, so it was definitely published in the early 2000's maybe even the 90's. the cover art was holographic i think and and had a picture of a face covering most of it.

these are all the details i remember. i hope i wasn't having a fever dream.

so this girl lives in the future with her selfish mom and she has like a closet where she can pick out clothes from a computer and change their color on the screen before putting them on? and i think she looks into a fountain that has like mirror pieces in it and she looks really hard at it and gets sucked into it to another time or possibly another world? it's very primitive and she doesn't adapt very well.

i remember she had some kind of implant in her arm like a communication device. she discovers that the angle of the reflection of the mirror piece caused the sudden transportation. she later goes back to her own world and brings back medicine for the people of the primitive world that she visited.

where she comes from it's all very futuristic and fancy and has a lot of technology and i remember she had a weird name like glimmer or something like that

any help would be appreciated this story has been gnawing at my subconscious literally for years. it was one of my favorite stories when i was younger and it's probably not even that good now but i would still like to know the title!! thanks again.

Comment: Was there a dog who served crumpets?

Comment: i don't remember that detail :-/

Comment: I ask because I'm sure I read a series of YA fiction books with this premise; The fountain/sculpture was a device for travelling between universes used by an experienced traveller, and the main character found fulfilment in worlds not dominated by advertising ("but the expense!") and shallow for-show social events. The experienced traveller's manservant was a canine refugee from a world where animals with humanlike intelligence were persecuted. This sounds very like what you describe, but for the life of me I can't remember the title or author...

Comment: I don't think you're describing my story. as far as I can remember this wasn't a series it was a standalone novel. the main character wasn't exactly experienced and basically found the portal by accident and it only transported her to one place and back. and I don't remember anything about an intelligent dog. it mostly had something to do with a mirror/reflection and not the fountain itself. I think she also realizes how shitty her actual world is? like she starts to notice poverty or something like that.ugh the struggle is so real.

Comment: That still sounds like the series I'm vaguely remembering; Note that the experienced traveller is a person the main character meets, not the main character herself. That said, I still can't remember the name.

Comment: aah well, thank you anyway. there has to be some record of it somewhere right :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Mirror, Mirror](http://www.louisecooper.com/fiction/ya_mirrormirror.html) trilogy by Louise Cooper, consisting of *Breaking Through*, *Running Free*, and *Testing Limits*.

> In Eurostate-8 (the country once known as England), Angel Ashe approaches her fifteenth birthday. Life here is an endless round of round of computer-controlled luxury, commercial sponsorship and artificial, virtual-reality 'experience'. But Angel longs for more than this ersatz existence… and she has found a way to break free and unlock the doors to something more real. It's easy. The answer lies in her own reflection...

I googled everything I could think of but in the end, my original gut instinct that it was called the Mirror, Mirror trilogy was correct.

Comment: Can you include some details, such as excerpts from the book, that support this?

Comment: I can provide the synopsis from the website if that's any help? The first book is called Breaking Free

In Eurostate-8 (the country once known as England), Angel Ashe approaches her fifteenth birthday. Life here is an endless round of round of computer-controlled luxury, commercial sponsorship and artificial, virtual-reality 'experience'. But Angel longs for more than this ersatz existence… and she has found a way to break free and unlock the doors to something more real. It's easy. The answer lies in her own reflection...

Comment: Yes. Quoting a synopsis from a website, either the author's or something like Goodreads or Wikipedia generally works.

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU!!!!!! THAT'S THE BOOK!